# Json to pojo convertions

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

How we convert following type of json into java object

```
{
    "complaint_Map": {
        "1000067730": "3011351597604397",
        "1000067730-06": "10582576134561065"
    }
}
```

if anyone have any idea about this tell how we do that.

Comment: use jackson or gson

Comment: What have you tried? What's the reason the question to be tagged with `spring-boot`?

Comment: because in my spring-boot project i have requirement to move username base  data to policy baised data from RIAK KV buckets to another buckets of another server, thats why but spring-boot tag is not required here!!!

Answer (score 0):

With jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Try

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{\"complaint_Map\":{\"1000067730\":\"3011351597604397\",\"1000067730-06\":\"10582576134561065\"}}";
Map<String,Object> pojo = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Map.class);
System.out.println(((Map<String,Object>)pojo.get("complaint_Map")).get("1000067730")+"");
```

will print

```
 3011351597604397
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use Jackson library that converts a simple POJO to/from JSON.

From Wikipedia:

> Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor for Java. Developers of it extol the combination of fast, correct, lightweight, and ergonomic attributes of the library.

Here an example taken by Wikipedia:

```
public class ReadWriteJackson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInput = 
          "{\"id\":0,\"firstName\":\"Robin\",\"lastName\":\"Wilson\"}";
        Person q = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, Person.class);
        System.out.println("Read and parsed Person from JSON: " + q);

        Person p = new Person("Roger", "Rabbit");
        System.out.print("Person object " + p + " as JSON = ");
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ObjectMapper from jackson.

Suppose the json is defines a java object,
then it can be done by

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

YourObject mappingClassObject = new YourObject();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
try{
   mappingClassObject = mapper.readValue(yourJSON, YourObject.class);
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution using `Jackson` library, here it is.

The custom class:

```
@JsonRootName("complaint_Map")
public class Complaint {
    private String firstKey;
    private String secondKey;

    @JsonProperty("1000067730")
    public String getFirstKey() {
        return firstKey;
    }
    @JsonProperty("1000067730")
    public void setFirstKey(String firstKey) {
        this.firstKey = firstKey;
    }

    @JsonProperty("1000067730-06")
    public String getSecondKey() {
        return secondKey;
    }

    @JsonProperty("1000067730-06")
    public void setSecondKey(String secondKey) {
        this.secondKey = secondKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Complaint{" +
                "firstKey='" + firstKey + '\'' +
                ", secondKey='" + secondKey + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the way of testing:

```
String jsonString = "{\"complaint_Map\":{\"1000067730\":\"3011351597604397\",\"1000067730-06\":\"10582576134561065\"}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
try {
    Complaint complaint = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Complaint.class);
    System.out.println(complaint);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used the following version (in `Maven pom`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```