# Clean string from backslashs and put the results into data strucutre

Tags: java, string, data-structures

I have this string

```
"[{\"name\":\"john\",\"family\":[],\"status\":\"single\"},{\"name\":\"david\",\"family\":[],\"status\":\"marred\"}]"
```

how can I clean up the backslashs from this string and put the entities into a data structure?

Comment: You mean you want to parse the json into a structure?

Comment: yes but the input is string not json

Comment: Did you try replace method of string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is the first character of the string a `"` or a `[`?

Comment: But json is a string, just with specific structure.

Comment: the first character is `"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to UNESCAPE String while converting java object to JSON string using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706849/how-to-unescape-string-while-converting-java-object-to-json-string-using-jackson)

Comment: There are no backslashes in the String. You should read about basic Java escaping rules for Strings.

Comment: I assume this is direct from Java code and the backslashes are simply escaping the double quotation marks so they can be embedded into a Java String in code?
Gyro Gearless (I was obviously typing the same!)

Comment: @Catalina you dont have to escape the slashes ur string works fine , see the answer I have posted using the exact same string u posted.

Comment: You said the first character of the string was `"`. The fact that you accepted an answer where the first character is `[` determined that was a lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException, JSONException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = "[{\"name\":\"john\",\"family\":[],\"status\":\"single\"},{\"name\":\"david\",\"family\":[],\"status\":\"marred\"}]";
        List<CustomClass> datas = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<CustomClass>>() {});
        System.out.println(datas);
    }
}

class CustomClass {
    public String name;
    public List<CustomClass> family;
    public String status;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [name=" + name + ", family=" + family + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }
}
```

**output**

```
[Data [name=john, family=[], status=single], Data [name=david, family=[], status=marred]]
```

Comment: while trying to save the object into elasticsearch i am getting the following error:
`nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_state_exception, reason=Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:731]];`

Comment: That might be a different issue, can u paste the code on how u r passing it to elastic search ?

Comment: @Catalina this is what I found when I googled ""The message "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT" means that Elasticsearch was expecting an entry of type "string" but you are trying to give an object as input.""

Comment: it looks like elasticserch only accept string to store?

Comment: @Catalina after above code , try this String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(datas); then send try sendin this to Elastic Search, P.S i have not work much or know about ES

Answer (score 0):

The string looks okay. The escaping is done to use the string within java.

Use a library like [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7). For your task.

- [Complete read/write example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740360/1485527)
- [Example on how to read json to a map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43367183/1485527)
- [Example on how to read json to a JsonNode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072452/1485527)

Answer (score -1):

Written in jshell console so you need to add classes etc as needed

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

try {
    String json = "[{\"name\":\"john\",\"family\":[],\"status\":\"single\"},{\"name\":\"david\",\"family\":[],\"status\":\"marred\"}]";
    json = json.replace("\\\"", "\"");
    System.out.println(json);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Person[] persons = mapper.readValue(json, Person[].class);
    System.out.println(persons[0].name);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

static class Person {

    public final String name;
    public final String[] family;
    public final String status;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("family") String[] family,
            @JsonProperty("status") String status
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your replace() is a no-op - there is no need to replace anything! Just try to comment the line with the .replace() and see if it makes any difference...

Comment: Actually given the question and the test data it works just fine. But i see from the subsequent discussion that it wasn't exactly what the he was after but rather just parsing a json response. I'll leave it anyways, it's not totally impossible one would encounter data stored in a DB or file like that...